# How to get plain text from NFC Tag?

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc, reader

I have tried to implement the code from Google documentation but it is still not clear for me. What am I missing here?

This is method in MainActivity.java:

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMessages =
                intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMessages != null) {
            NdefMessage[] messages = new NdefMessage[rawMessages.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMessages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[i];
                Log.i("nfcccc",messages[i].toString());
            }
            // Process the messages array.
            Log.i("from tag: ",messages.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this,messages.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

In onCreated method I have also initialized nfcAdapter:

```
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
```

In manifest file I have this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>
```

I spent couple of days trying to implement that, but it is still not working.
**What I am doing is that I use NFC Tools android app to save plain text and the I want to read this data in my own app>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the interaction with the Activity's launch mode as NFC handling is done by another System App and then with what Google document as how to use NFC it is just like your application is receiving data from another App.

So `onNewIntent`

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Your application will have launchMode as `standard` as default therefore `onNewIntent` is never called

There are 2 standard parts for using the old NFC API's with Intents

1. Activity is not running (which usually means the App Task is not running), set manifest filters in Activity and then in `oncreate` use `getIntent` and then process the Intent for being an NFC based Intent (as per you would do on `onNewIntent`)
2. Activity (and App) is running and in the foreground, `enableForegroundDispatch` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch which basically tells the NFC system app to restart this Activity when it is the "Top" activity as though it was a "singleTop" Activity, then `onNewIntent` is called by the incoming Intent (This has a negative side effect of Pausing and Resuming your Activity)

Note there are different ways to setup launchMode and what Activity is top of the stack to get it to tie up sending the Intent to `onNewIntent` but they are less common.
Best to handle NFC Intents in `onCreate` and also`enableForegroundDispatch` with the same handling in `onNewIntent`

An even better way to get more control is use the newer and better `enableReaderMode` API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)

**Summary**
So just add the code for `foregroundDispatch` as per https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Thats works However I am getting rubbish data before String that I saved. For example: if Tag contains string "Hello" I will get "_ TenHello". Do you have any idea what might be the problem? Maybe I should extract just part of the byte array and then convert it to the string?

Comment: Text Records are encoded with Language see my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515909/2373819