# Android, Kotlin: Checking if an NdefMessage converted to a String is equal to another String

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I am trying to check if a value read from an NFC tag is equal to a String. The value written in the tag is correctly extracted, but when I try to compare the value with another string, as in the second "if" statement, it will always enter the "else" block.

```
private fun processNdefMessages(ndefMessages: Array<NdefMessage?>) {
        var msg =  ""
        for (curMsg in ndefMessages) {
            if (curMsg != null) {
                // get the text written in the tag
                msg = String(curMsg.getRecords().get(0).getPayload())
            }
        }
        textFromTag = msg
        if (textFromTag.equals("enjacket1")) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "jacket1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$textFromTag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

EDIT: Also, when I read the payload from the tag, it always starts with "en" and then the actual string. This is why I compare the `textFromTag` with "enjacket1". I tried to eliminate the first two charaacters, but nothing seems to make a change to it...

Comment: Have you checked what the actual value for `textFromTag` is?

Comment: Yes, I checked and it's exactly the same as in the case there would be only the Toast from the else block instead of the if statement.

Comment: The `en` is the language encoding full details about Ndef text encoding is in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515909/2373819

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because there is an extra byte in front of the language `en` characters to specify the language length which is probably not printable.

As NFC text is encoded as:

- language length (1 byte) + language (n bytes) + Text

So read the first byte and trim accordingly or quick hack trim the first 3 bytes off for english messages.

More details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515909/2373819