# Android NFC - Mifare Classic Restore and Transfer not working

Tags: android, nfc, restore, transfer, mifare

According to documentation;

> Restore: Moves the contents of a block into the internal Transfer
> Buffer
>
> Transfer: Writes the contents of the internal Transfer Buffer to a
> value block

So want to move some data from x block to y block.

[image]

According to access conditions, **Sector 3** supports `transfer` and `restore`.

[image]

Also **Block 12** have a data `quickappdemotest`. I want to move it from **Block 12** to **Block 13** by using `restore` and `transfer` methods but somehow it did not work.

```
MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get(tag);
try {
    mfc.connect();
    boolean authA = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(3, MifareClassic.KEY_NFC_FORUM);
    if (authA) {
        mfc.restore(12);
        mfc.transfer(13);
    }
    mfc.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

It does not throw any exception but after method completes, when I checked from the app only **Block 12** have `quickapptestdemo` data.

Can anyone give me clue?

Answer (score 0):

restore command needs block formatted as value block
example for block 12:
FF00000000FFFFFFFF0000000CF30CF3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The transfer operation only works on value blocks, two conditions must be filled:

- You need permission to do a transfer, this depends on the access bits
- The block must be formatted as value block, you need to initialize the value of the block with a write operation before using it a value block

The value block format looks like this:
[image]

For example, a value of 390 would look like this (mind that numbers are stored as little endian, LSB first)

```
 value     ~value    value    address
|-------| |-------| |-------| |-------|
8601 0000 79fe ffff 8601 0000 00ff 00ff
```

The value of the address does not really matter, as long as the formatting is OK

For more info, check out chapter 8.6.2.1 [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf)