# How to read text data from NFC ntag215 with python?

Tags: python-3.x, nfc, pn532

I am using a raspberry pi with NFC reader module PN532 by Waveshare.

I have ntag215 which I would like to read the text data that was written to it using NFC Tools app downloaded from Google Playstore. The data written was *hello_world*. When I run the following python script and print out the written data, output printed: *bytearray(b'nhel')* instead of *hello_world*. Where did I go wrong? How do I output the full string *hello_world*?

My code:

```
"""
This example shows connecting to the PN532 with I2C (requires clock
stretching support), SPI, or UART. SPI is best, it uses the most pins but
is the most reliable and universally supported.
After initialization, try waving various 13.56MHz RFID cards over it!
"""

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import codecs
from pn532 import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        pn532 = PN532_SPI(debug=False, reset=20, cs=4)
        #pn532 = PN532_I2C(debug=False, reset=20, req=16)
        #pn532 = PN532_UART(debug=False, reset=20)

        ic, ver, rev, support = pn532.get_firmware_version()
        print('Found PN532 with firmware version: {0}.{1}'.format(ver, rev))

        # Configure PN532 to communicate with MiFare cards
        pn532.SAM_configuration()

        print('Waiting for RFID/NFC card...')
        while True:
            # Check if a card is available to read
            uid = pn532.read_passive_target(timeout=5)
            print('.', end="")
            # Try again if no card is available.
            if uid is None:
                continue
            print('Found card with UID:', [hex(i) for i in uid])
             ntag2xx_block = pn532.ntag2xx_read_block(6)
            print(ntag2xx_block)
            
            for i in uid:
                print(hex(i))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Android NFC reader add's "en" before the message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515271/why-android-nfc-reader-adds-en-before-the-message)

Comment: As well as the standard text record language header, you don't seem to read enough data may be use a better library like https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tag.html to read Ndef

Comment: Could u give a working example to read the text data hello_world with nfcpy?

Comment: Check out the examples programs of nfcpy https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/tagtool.html

Comment: i am using PN532 NFC reader with SPI comm protocol. Seems that nfcpy only works with USB readers?